# Add validation on numeric column when user fills control using coma

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column-formula, column-validation

I need to add validation on a numeric column. An error should be when the user fills the control with a decimal number using a comma instead of a dot.

I have a formula which looks like this:

```
=AND(IF(ISERROR(FIND(",", MyNumericColumn)),TRUE))
```

And it doesn't work. But if I change the character to a dot".", it will find it correctly. Any ideas how to add validation on comma?

Answer (score 0):

As per my test, I am not able to find the comma (`,`) in number column using SharePoint formulas. So, it is difficult to add such validations.

**Workaround**:

Use single line of text field instead of number column & use below column validation:

```
=ISNumber([MyColumnName] + 0)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this workaround will not work for me. Changing the column type involves a major rebuilding. This column has to be numeric.